# How to read data in vtkDataArray?

Tags: c++, vtk

I am ver new to VTK.
This is part of my code:

```
vtkDataSetReader *rdr = vtkDataSetReader::New();
rdr->SetFileName("proj7b.vtk");
rdr->SetScalarsName("hardyglobal");
rdr->Update();

int dims[3];
vtkRectilinearGrid *rgrid = (vtkRectilinearGrid *) rdr->GetOutput();
rgrid->GetDimensions(dims);



vtkDataArray *dataArray;
dataArray = vtkDoubleArray::New();

dataArray = rgrid->GetPointData()->GetScalars()->GetVoidPointer(0);

for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    cout<<"here----------"<<endl;
    cout<<" "<<dataArray[i]<<" ";
}
```

I want to read the data into my vtkDataArray. But this code cannot be compile:

```
proj7b.cxx:525:15: error: 
  assigning to 'vtkDataArray *' from incompatible type 'void *'
dataArray = rgrid->GetPointData()->GetScalars()->GetVoidPointer(0);
          ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

1 error generated.
Is there anyone knows how to read data into vtkDataArray?

Comment: The error message is self explanatory. You are pointer to "something" to vtkDataArray. What you need to ensure is: 1.) make sure this "something" can be represented by vtkDataArray. 2.) use static_cast<vtkDataArray*>()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vtk provides the method for it, you don't need to use the "low level" method:

rgrid->GetPointData()->GetArray(0)

or 
rgrid->GetPointData()->GetArray("arrayname")

It works the same way for FieldData and CellData ( http://www.vtk.org/doc/release/6.2/html/classvtkFieldData.html)

What you get is a vtkArray, not a simple c++ array, so you will have to read it like:

```
cout<<" "<<dataArray->GetValue(i) <<" ";
```

There are a lot of examples in the wiki http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx

Answer (score -1):

please see this page: *https://cloud.tencent.com/developer/ask/sof/148655*

```
void doSomething(vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataArray> dataArray)
{
  vtkIdType numTuples = dataArray->GetNumberOfTuples();
  for (vtkIdType tupleIdx = 0; tupleIdx < numTuples; ++tupleIdx)
  {
    double* tuple = dataArray->GetTuple(tupleIdx);
    for (int j = 0; j < /*¿¿¿???*/; ++j)
    {
      double var = tuple[j];
      // Do something with var
      // Carefull don't go out of bounds
    }
  }
}
```